# jq - filter using list of object identifier-index stored in a variable

Tags: json, jq

I'm writing a reusable Bash script that allows me to query an API to get data about parliamentary members and store it in csv format.

The json response of the API has a lot of keys (name, gender, birthdate, commission membership, vote...), and, depending on what I'd like to do, I do not always want to capture the same keys. So I would like to abstract this part of the code in order to be able to write:

```
mp_keys= a,b,c,d

curl https://mp.com | jq '. | [$mp_keys] | @csv'
```

so that it is interpreted by jq as

```
jq '. | [.a, .b, .c, .d] | @ csv'
```

I don't have a set structure for the variable format, so it could be:

- `mp_keys="a,b,c,d"` or
- `mp_keys=".a, .b, .c, .d"` or
- `mp_key1=a, mp_key2=b, mp_key3=c, mp_key4=d`

I know that in jq I can use the following structure:

```
jq --arg mp_key1 "${mp_key1}" --arg mp_key2 "${mp_key2}" --arg mp_key3 "${mp_key3}" --arg mp_key4 "${mp_key4}" '. 
| [.[$mp_key1], .[$mp_key2], .[$mp_key3], .[$mp_key4]] 
| @csv'
```

But it obviously becomes tedious very quickly.

Lastly I could also build the jq command as a string then apply `eval` to it but I would prefer using a proper jq solution.

### Edit

I will break down @peak's answer for future reference, as it's very useful to understand what's happening. His answer is reproduced below:

```
mp_keys="a,b,c,d"

echo '{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d": 4}' |
jq -r --arg mpk "$mp_keys" '
($mpk|split(",")) as $mpkeys
| [ .[ $mpkeys[] ] ]
| @csv '
```

First, it's important to understand that jq will:

1. evaluate the value of `$mpkeys` first, which implies doing the `split(",")` on `$mpk`
2. then pass the json sent through `echo`.

So we can do the same to understand what's happening. The `( )` tells jq to process this section in priority, so we can start by replacing the parenthesis with its results.

1. the string `"a,b,c,d"`, stored in `$mpk`, is split and stored into the array `["a","b","c","d"]` as described in the [section on `split(str)`of jq's manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions).
2. The array is subsequently stored into `$mpkeys` through `as`.

Which means that an equivalent of the initial code can be written as:

```
echo '{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d": 4}' |
jq -r --arg mpk "$mp_keys" '
["a","b","c","d] as $mpkeys
| [ .[ $mpkeys[] ] ]
| @csv '
```

Of course now the --arg is useless, as `$mpk` was there to hold our initial string. So we can simplify further with:

```
echo '{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d": 4}' |
jq -r '["a","b","c","d] as $mpkeys
| [ .[ $mpkeys[] ] ]
| @csv '
```

Let's now break down `[ .[ $mpkeys[] ] ]`:

- because `$mpkeys` is an array, `$mpkeys[]` stands for the individual elements of the array, equivalent to `"a","b","c","d"`. Instead of a single element (an array), we now have 4 elements (strings), which will be transformed individually by the filters around them (the brackets)
- `$mpkeys[]` is then wrapped into `.[]` which applies to each of the 4 elements, and is consequently equivalent to `.["a"]`, `.["b"]`, `.["c"]`, `.["d"]`. Each of those elements is a generic object index, which are equivalent to the object-identifier index form (`.a, .b, .c, .d`) as [described in jq's manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters).
- the final outer `[ ]` simply wraps everything inside an array, which is necessary to pass the result to `@csv`.

So the equivalent to the code above is:

```
echo '{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d": 4}' |
jq -r '["a","b","c","d] as $mpkeys
| [ .["a"], .["b"], .["c"], .["d"] ]
| @csv '
```

Here `$mpkeys` serves no purpose, so we actually have:

```
 echo '{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d": 4}' |
jq -r ' [ .["a"], .["b"], .["c"], .["d"] ]
| @csv '
```

There we are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your approach:

```
mp_keys="a,b,c,d"

echo '{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d": 4}' |
  jq -r --arg mpk "$mp_keys" '
    ($mpk|split(",")) as $mpkeys
    | [ .[ $mpkeys[] ] ]
    | @csv '
```

would yield:

```
1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly and that's a very useful example use of ``as``. Could you explain break down what happens with $mpkeys? I understand that the outer brackets ``[ ]`` hold the final array, and the middle brackets ``.[ ]`` produce the identifier by associating the dot and the string. But I'm not sure why the inner brackets ``$mpkeys[]`` are necessary.

Comment: See the subsection “Array/Object Value Iterator” in the online manual https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters

Comment: Maybe it's obvious but I'm still not sure what's happening. once jq does the split, it holds the values of ``mp_keys`` in an array ``["a", "b", "c", "d"]``. Then it passes it each array element one after the other to the next section where they are processed, but I don't see the use of outputting ``[ .[ a[] ], [ .[ b[] ]`` etc. I know I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: The second sentence above is quite wrong. Using `debug` and/or experimenting with .[] should help clarify things. You might like to use jqplay.org

Comment: thanks for the debug tip @peak, that was key to experiment on the command line. I edited my question to add a breakdown of your answer for others to see.